# getting warning while running protractor-conf.js file:" Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues"

Tags: node.js, protractor

I am using protractor-cucumber framework. But while running it it gives me warning " `Buffer()` is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the `Buffer.alloc()`, `Buffer.allocUnsafe()`, or `Buffer.from()` methods instead."

1. **node version: v10.15.3**
2. **npm version: 6.4.1**

   ```
   {
      "dependencies": {
                        "chai": "4.1.2",
                        "cucumber": "4.2.1",
                        "protractor": "^5.4.2",
                        "protractor-cucumber-framework": "4.2.0"
                      }
   }
   ```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you can provide the full error message as the message typically contains a deprecation id and other useful information. Most likely the issue is about how a Buffer object is created in your code or in one of the dependencies. Btw, I think your question is a duplicate. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52165333/deprecationwarning-buffer-is-deprecated-due-to-security-and-usability-issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below dependency version

```
{
   "dependencies": {
                     "chai": "4.2.0",
                     "cucumber": "5.1.0",
                     "protractor": "^5.4.2",
                     "protractor-cucumber-framework": "6.1.1"
                   }
}
```

Hope it helps you