# DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), ... methods instead

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have an angular project and recently I have added angular-universal to it using the following command:

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject {{ name of your project }}
```

building and running it:

```
npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr
```

Ive got many errors after doing so but I managed to get it to work, but when I access my home page its writing the following to the console:

```
(node:44714) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
ERROR [Error]
ERROR [Error]
```

and each time I refresh the page it print `ERROR [Error]` again without any details, please note that I don't have any `new Buffer()` in my code, and I have followed the suggestions on stack overflow to solve this but no luck, can someone help to figure out what's causing this?

---

I have solved the `ERROR [Error]` by removing the TranslateService, but still having the deprecationWarning

Comment: Try passing `--trace-warnings` or `--trace-deprecation` options to nodejs when running `server.js` file (you need to modify the `serve:ssr` script). This should help you identify which packages cause problem

Comment: @David I don't have serve:ssr script all I do is yarn run serve:ssr , I tried running it like yarn run serve:ssr ----trace-warnings and yarn run --trace-warnings serve:ssr but nothing changed and nothing got printed on the console, can you suggest how to run the trace?

Comment: `serve:ssr` is normally a script defined in `package.json`. Passing the option to yarn is useless, you need to pass it to nodejs

Comment: @David thank you its working now I have got an exception caused by the server.js

Comment: Hi @KhaledJamal how did you solve the problem? I am also facing the same issue

Comment: @MadhavanSundararaj check out the above comments and try to debug the exception, if you got one share I might be able to help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues when i move my script to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52165333/deprecationwarning-buffer-is-deprecated-due-to-security-and-usability-issues)

Comment: @NebojsaSapic No I did not, the above comments helped me to solve the issue

Answer (score 29):

In case you're using `Buffer()` in your code just replace it with:

```
new Buffer(number) // Deprecated 
Buffer.alloc(number) // New
```

Or

```
new Buffer(string) // Deprecated 
Buffer.from(string) // New
```

In case you're **not** using `Buffer()` anywhere you have to do the following:

1) Search all of your app dependencies (You might use a tool for searching by clicking the search icon in the IDE your currently using and type `Buffer()`)

2) Wherever you find a `Buffer()` in a module or dependency just replace it as mentioned above

Comment: I have done what you have suggested the only place I can see Buffer is in package-lock.json file

Comment: @KhaledJamal Kindly tell me your nodejs and npm versions

Comment: node --version returns v10.15.1 and npm --version 6.8.0

Comment: I would recommend you to update both nodejs and npm to the latest versions , After that go to your project and delete the node_modules folder and re-install it by ``npm install``

Comment: To update see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-nodejs-and-npm-to-the-next-versions

Comment: I have npm in the latest version. There is no `buffer()` in any file except the package-lock.json. The dependencies are `safe-buffer` and `safer-buffer`. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I am getting the same warning, it doesn't seem to affect anything at all.
I did the find & replace but guess what, there is nothing in my code (neither in the source nor in the compiled bundle) that matches Buffer() so I am pretty curious about it.
I have the latest LTS version of node (12.14.1) but I upgraded npm to 6.13.6
Also I have to say that the client version does not produce that output if deployed to my production or development server, it only happens when serving the SSR version via iisnode, i don't know if that helps.