# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token for .js.gz file, compressed angular build hosted on IIS

Tags: javascript, angular, iis

I was trying to compress and host my angular app on the IIS locally for that I followed the following steps

1)ng build  --output-path="dist/debug" && gzipper compress --output-file-format [filename].[ext].[compressExt] ./dist ./dist/user-zip

using the above command built the app and compressed it using gzipper and copied the gzip build to prodbuild folder

2)Created an application on the IIS and pointed to prodbuild folder

3)Created a web.config in the user-zip folder added a web.config with the following changes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires" httpExpires="Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".js.gz" mimeType="application/javascript" />
    </staticContent>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <location path="prodbuild">
    <system.webServer>
      <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
      <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
            <add name="content-encoding" value="gzip" />
         </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

4. In the index.html  made the following changes to point to the  .gz files

   ```
    <script src="runtime-es2015.js.gz" type="module"></script>
    <script src="runtime-es5.js.gz" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es5.js.gz" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es2015.js.gz" type="module"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js.gz" defer></script>
    <script src="vendor-es2015.js.gz" type="module"></script><script src="vendor-es5.js.gz" nomodule defer></script>
   <script src="main-es2015.js.gz" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.js.gz" nomodule defer></script>
   ```

5)Tried to browse the app from IIS and faced the following issue
[image]

6)Tried to check the network tab and found in response header content-encoding is not getting set to gzip
[image]

how to solve the issue,as I already configured it in web.config for content-encoding to gzip where i'm going wrong how can i get the app working on local IIS

or is there anyway to pre compress angular build and host it on IIS locally to test other than the one I used

Comment: IIS has a module called Compression. You need to check  Enable dynamic content compression and apply it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cc4s.png

Answer (score 0):

Was  able to resolve it ,by following the steps as below

1)Updated web.config is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <configuration>
          <system.webServer>
            <staticContent>
              <mimeMap fileExtension=".js.gz" mimeType="application/javascript" />
            </staticContent>
                <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
                <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" />'
                
          </system.webServer>
          <location path="gz">
                <system.webServer>
                <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
                <httpProtocol>
                    <customHeaders>
                        <add name="content-encoding" value="gzip" />
                    </customHeaders>
                </httpProtocol>
            </system.webServer>
        </location>
        </configuration>
```

2)created a gz folder inside the prodBuild and moved .gz files inside it

3)Updated the file paths in the index.html to point to the gz files

```
<script src="./gz/runtime-es2015.js.gz" type="module"></script>
<script src="./gz/runtime-es5.js.gz" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="./gz/polyfills-es5.js.gz" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="./gz/polyfills-es2015.js.gz" type="module"></script>
<script src="./gz/scripts.js.gz" defer></script><script src="./gz/vendor-es2015.js.gz" type="module"></script>
<script src="./gz/vendor-es5.js.gz" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="./gz/main-es2015.js.gz" type="module"></script>
<script src="./gz/main-es5.js.gz" nomodule defer></script>
```