# A use of Symbol.species on the Node.js Buffer class to create a FastBuffer that doesn't make much sense

Tags: node.js, typescript, buffer

I came across [the following code](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Awebsockets%2Fws%20FastBuffer&type=code) looking at the [source of `ws`](https://github.com/websockets/ws) (a popular WebSocket implementation for Node.js):

```js
const FastBuffer = Buffer[Symbol.species];
```

So, how do they use this `FastBuffer`? Well, no custom implementations or any added code, they just use it to make `Buffer` instances from other buffers:

```js
this._buffers[0] = new FastBuffer(
  buf.buffer,
  buf.byteOffset + n,
  buf.length - n
);
```

```js
return new FastBuffer(buf.buffer, buf.byteOffset, n);
```

It is well known that the `Buffer` constructors [are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52165333/deprecationwarning-buffer-is-deprecated-due-to-security-and-usability-issues), but aside from that I couldn't even find a constructor definition that receives an `offset` and a `length` like the one that `ws` seems to be using.

What is this code doing under the hood to access that constructor? How does this add performance? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Seems like Node.js [also defines a `FastBuffer`](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Anodejs%2Fnode%20FastBuffer&type=code) for the Node internals, but it inherits directly from `Uint8Array` rather than using this trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is this code doing under the hood to access that constructor?

Let's start with the purpose of the [`Symbol.species`/`@@species`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species) pattern: It allows subclasses to define what constructor should be used to create new instances. You would often use it on an *instance* you wanted to copy (`someObject.constructor[Symbol.species]`), but you can use it on the class directly.

Looking at [what it returns](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/de4553f3d11f07fa63e19069daa1b0890052d8b2/lib/buffer.js#L282), it's [the `FastBuffer` class that Node.js uses internally](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/de4553f3d11f07fa63e19069daa1b0890052d8b2/lib/internal/buffer.js#L956) (those line numbers will rot), which is a class inheriting directly from `Uint8Array` (not from `Buffer`).

The fact that `Buffer` supports `@@species` [is not documented](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/buffer.html), so the code you're quoting would appear to be hooking into and relying on Node.js internals.

> How does this add performance?

I can't point to something specific, but presumably the Node.js implementers called it `FastBuffer` for a reason. :-) Probably by not being a full `Buffer` it can have optimizations that `Buffer` can't have.

> Is this documented somewhere?

It's hard to prove a negative, but the `@@species` on `Buffer` isn't, nor does a search for `FastBuffer` on the Node.js API docs turn anything up.

> It is well known that the `Buffer` constructors are deprecated, but aside from that I couldn't even find a constructor definition that receives an `offset` and a `length` like the one that `ws` seems to be using.

Since what we're getting back isn't necessarily a `Buffer`, it doesn't really matter, but `Buffer` [*does* have that constructor](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/buffer.html#new-bufferarraybuffer-byteoffset-length). But more importantly, the (internal?) `FastBuffer` class supports that signature, as does its parent class [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array/Uint8Array).